# or in if statement - one condition of the two met

Tags: python, boolean-logic

This is my code:

```
s = "/test"
a = "/api/"

# path == "/api/"

if not request.path.startswith(s) or not request.path.startswith(a):
   print "is's ok!"
```

Why my `print` is not displayed?

Comment: Your `print` should **always** display with that logic, because your tests cannot produce `False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `print` statement is in fact *always* displayed. That's because at least one of the two tests will *always* be true. If the path starts with one string, it can't start with another, so if one of the two conditions is false, the other is certainly going to be true:

```
>>> def tests(path):
...     print not bool(path.startswith('/test'))
...     print not bool(path.startswith('/api/'))
...
>>> tests('/api/')
True
False
>>> tests('/test')
False
True
>>> tests('')  # or any other string not starting with /test or /api/
True
True
```

You probably want to use `and` instead, so *both* tests must be true:

```
if not request.path.startswith(s) and not request.path.startswith(a):
```

or use parentheses and one `not`, i.e. only execute the `print` if the path does not start with either option:

```
if not (request.path.startswith(s) or request.path.startswith(a)):
```

Comment: Doesn't that mean that the `print` will always be displayed in OP's code?

Comment: @interjay: it'll indeed always display. The OP did not test their code correctly.

Comment: @Holloway: ick, forgot to edit that part, thanks for the heads-up!